# Multiple join with the same table count

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, sql-server-2016

I have a table structure similar to below:

```
declare @t1 table (code varchar)
declare @t2 table (id int, code varchar, closed bit)
```

@t2 holds open/close for the codes in @t1:

```
insert into @t1 values ('x')

insert into @t2 values (1, 'x', 1)
insert into @t2 values (2, 'x', 1)
insert into @t2 values (3, 'x', 0)
```

I'm trying to get the count of open/close for a code:

```
select 
count (t2_open.id) as opencount
, count (t2_closed.id) as closecount
from @t1 t1
inner join @t2 t2_open on t2_open.code = t1.code AND t2_open.closed = 0
inner join @t2 t2_closed on t2_closed.code = t1.code AND t2_closed.closed = 1
```

Which returns 2 & 2, I can't see what I'm doing wrong here, why doesn't it return 1 & 2?

Shouldn't selecting * from my query return null and the correct count when the records don't match? I was expecting select * to return 3 records, but it's returning 2 records where the id is 3 in both rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting the total records not the individual values

```
SELECT t1.code,
       Count (CASE WHEN t2.closed = 1 THEN 1 END) AS opencount,
       Count (CASE WHEN t2.closed = 0 THEN 1 END) AS closecount
FROM   @t1 t1
       LEFT JOIN @t2 t2
              ON t2.code = t1.code
GROUP  BY t1.code
```

**Update :**

Lets break down the joins

```
SELECT t1.code,t2_open.closed
FROM   @t1 t1
       INNER JOIN @t2 t2_open
               ON t2_open.code = t1.code
                  AND t2_open.closed = 0
```

In first join you are pulling the records where closed = 0 so the result will be like

```
+------+--------+
| code | closed |
+------+--------+
| x    |      0 |
+------+--------+
```

Now on top of above result you are joining @t2 with code and closed = 1

```
SELECT t1.code,t2_open.closed,t2_closed.closed
FROM   @t1 t1
       INNER JOIN @t2 t2_open
               ON t2_open.code = t1.code
                  AND t2_open.closed = 0
       INNER JOIN @t2 t2_closed
               ON t2_closed.code = t1.code
                  AND t2_closed.closed = 1
```

We have two records with closed = 1 and for same code, when we join with previous result closed will also be repeated twice because two closed = 1

```
+------+--------+--------+
| code | closed | closed |
+------+--------+--------+
| x    |      0 |      1 |
| x    |      0 |      1 |
+------+--------+--------+
```

As you can see, we have two closed = 0 after joining so when counting you are seeing two close count

Comment: Sorry, can you explain bit more why my code didn't work? When the condition is on the join and the join type is inner, should selecting * from my query return null and the correct count when the records don't match? I was expecting select * to return 3 records, but it's returning 2 records where the id is 3 in both rows.

Comment: @curious - check the update. AM not good in giving explanations. Tell me if you are still having doubt